# How to make a button responsive?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap .
Can anyone tell me how to make a button responsive ?

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Forgot Password" />
```

Comment: you can add a span# (.span1, .span2, etc) class to a button. I.E. if you add span12 the button will fill its container.

Comment: Can't you just use `@media` in your CSS: `@media only screen and (max-width : 650px) and (min-width : 481px)`

Comment: "Responsive" is just a meaningless buzzword.  What exactly do you want the button to do?  What do you want it to "respond" to?

Comment: You can handle the responsiveness of button using javascript by using the resize events on the `window` and scaling the button's `width` and `height`.

Answer (score 4):

> Responsive" is just a meaningless buzzword. What exactly do you want
>   the button to do? What do you want it to "respond" to? – Rocket Hazmat

User RocketHazmat is close to what i would yell the hell out in you ears. **The button is already in a context of responDING in a fluid html frame**

You want to make your button adapt to width of container ? Just give it the class needed.

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" value="Forgot Password" />
```

or

```
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Forgot Password" style="width:100%" />
```

See this : http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons